# Android include native lib from native code at runtime

Tags: java, android, c++, linux, android-ndk

I have a app that uses native support from the ndk.

I want to know how to load a native lib FROM `C/C++` CODE at runtime and use it. Like say I made some extension pack for may app and want to call a known function (say `startPoint()`) which is compulsorily defined in each of the extension libs. Assume extensions to be like `DLCs` to a game

Basically the user must be able to download the lib.so file from some source to a app dedicated directory on the phone and then call the known entry point function in the lib.

ALL THIS MUST HAPPEN USING THE `C/C++` CODE IN THE LIB INCLUDED WITH THE APK NOT JAVA
In case of java one would use `System.loadLibrary("path/libname.so")` is there something like that in `c/c++` code to do in runtime ?

The main reason I don't want to keep everything in one lib is that the extensions will be made gradually over time and should be a choice of the user which to include. Also providing extension libs using play store updates will annoy users as it requires a complete re-download of the app and over time the combined size will increase to like 100+ mb

Comment: dlopen() is the native invocation of the dynamic linker.  Incidentally, System.loadLibrary() does not take a path and file name with lib- prefix and .so extension - though plain System.load() does.

Comment: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/theproblem.html 

Ahh... dear God help me!

Comment: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/thesolution.html

Mein gott !

Danke chris